# How to validate attachment in nested model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a Design model that has two Paperclip attachments inside two associations (full_image and preview). I want to be able to save designs only when both full_image and preview have valid files but can't seem to be able to make it work. Right now this is what I expected to work, but it doesn't just doesn't validate the attachments when I submit the form.

```
class Design < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :full_image, :as => :assetable, :class_name => "FullImage", :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :preview   , :as => :assetable, :class_name => "Preview"  , :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :full_image, :preview
  validates_associated :preview, :full_image

end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :assetable, :polymorphic => true
    delegate :url, :to => :attachment
end

class FullImage < Asset
    has_attached_file :attachment
    validates_attachment_presence :attachment
end

class Preview < Asset
    has_attached_file :attachment
    validates_attachment_presence :attachment
end
```

Could someone please suggest what I should be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I got it working

```
class Design < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :full_image, :as => :assetable, :class_name => "FullImage", :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :preview   , :as => :assetable, :class_name => "Preview"  , :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :full_image, :preview

  validates_presence_of :preview
  validates_presence_of :full_image

end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :assetable, :polymorphic => true
    delegate :url, :to => :attachment
end

class FullImage < Asset
    has_attached_file :attachment
end

class Preview < Asset
    has_attached_file :attachment
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :
validates :attachment,  :presence => true
inside the associated model instead of validates_attachment_presence